# Weird behavior of Jquery .html method on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to add a form dinamically to a div:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some_url",
  data: "some_data",
  success: function(html) {
    $( '#some_div' ).empty();
    $( '#some_div' ).html(html);
    ...
  }
 });
```

The html returned by the server looks like this:

```
<form id="form_id_alinea" method="post" action="fkAlinea">
  <div id="div-ds_alinea">
    <label>label: </label>
    <input type="text"id="ds_alinea" value="" />
    <div id="ds_alinea"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that this code works flawless on Firefox, but not on Google Chrome. When i first click the link to fetch the html from the server, the `form` is ripped of, and is not rendered inside the div, resulting in something like this:

```
<div id="some_div">
  <div id="div-ds_alinea">
    <label>label: </label>
    <input type="text"id="ds_alinea" value="" />
    <div id="ds_alinea"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed the code for using `append` instead and it worked. But i was wondering what kind of evil malicious entity are affecting the code, so the `.html()` method fails to work on Google's browser.

Comment: Try using `$.parseHTML(html)` before passing it to `.html()` (jQuery 1.8+)

Comment: @KevinB We are using an old version of Jquery.

Comment: Is `#some_div` inside of a `form`? You can't have nested `form` elements...

Comment: Oh, you guys nailed it. It is inside a form, but why did it worked with append and not with html?

Comment: because they use different methods of inserting content.

Comment: I would be pleased to accept any of your comments as an answer.